# Убил систему утилитой dd. Что теперь делать?

Tags: linux, dd

Такая беда... Хотел записать образ любимой Lubuntu на флешку и случайно перепутал букву, написал вместо "sdb" "sda". Заметил не сразу, т. е., утилита работала некоторое время, затем была в панике прервана аварийно. На компе теперь вместо обычных разделов типа "sda1" "sda2" и т. д. несколько "zram". Что теперь делать? Надо фоточки спасти а желательно вообще свести последствия оплошности к минимуму или даже все починить...

Comment: Грузимся с Live образа, подключаем внешний диск (желательно раза в три большего объёма, чем тот, с которого надо спасать информацию), запускаем `photorec`.

Comment: Я бы сначала снял бы дамп всего диска через `ddrescue` и ковырял бы уже его.

Кстати. Винт или ссд? Если ссд - без вариантов всё потерялось.

Comment: мысли в слух.

судя по описанному dd потёрла ПЕРВЫЕ 2-3 гига на диске (размером с iso Lubuntu). 
Что это значит:
1. винду уже не восстановить (как я понял это первый раздел)
2. таблица разделов тоже накрылась так как она расположена в самом начале диска, но 
если винда новая то на диске скорее всего использовалась таблица разделов GPT которая имеет резервную копию в конце диска.
----
то есть, по сути для восстановления всех разделов достаточно было скопировать резервную копию в начало диска что позволило бы восстановить доступ ко всем файловым системам кроме тех что находились в 2-3гиг

Answer (score 0):

Помогла программа Hetman Partition Recovery

Comment: было бы неплохо, если бы вы рассказали, как именно она помогла

Comment: Да как... Я не стал особо париться по поводу предварительного бэкапа, просто подключил пострадавший винт к стационаррику, запустил глубокий анализ, подождал 3 дня... Потом кнопку "восстановить" или что-то вродо того, просто сейчас уже не помню, потом указал папку для восстановленных файлов и подтвердил выбор кнопкой Ок. В общем, как-то так. В итоге удалось восстановить практически весь архив фотографий на ext4, с сохранением дерева каталогов, а вот виндовый раздел превратился в какую-то кашу. Но там каша, по сути, и до аварии была. Короче,  все оказалось очень просто, только долго.

Comment: Это надо написать в самом ответе, возможно пригодится для будущих посетителей.